# Netbeans REST client for PHP application?

Tags: php, rest, netbeans

I'm currently developing a small application in Zend Framework 2, which uses a RESTful API. I am currently working in Netbeans. I want a way to test my application from within Netbeans, sending various requests - is this possible?

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.1.

I know PHPStorm has something similar (http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/02/using-the-rest-client-within-phpstorm/) but is there something like this in Netbeans?

Comment: As additional option to a UI plugin for netbeans to test an (REST) API you could use curl in the CLI of Netbeans.

Comment: Good idea! If I cannot find a nice UI for Netbeans I will look into this option.

Comment: If you might find anything let us know! Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no (maybe there is some plugin for it). But with 7.4 (now in Beta), there is a new tool for PHP/HTML5 projects called Network Monitor where you can see all requests made from your application (including websockets) and corresponding headers and responses. So if you create some interface for performing such requests, you can see details about them in NetBeans. But you cannot make requests from NetBeans (of course the terminal way in comment above is possible)